# Какой фреймворк наряду с React рекомендуется для разработки фронтенд-части для CMS Magento?

Tags: reactjs, seo, magento, ssr, ecommerce

Для разработки frontend-части CMS Magento ищу рекомендации по выбору фреймворка с учетом следующих критериев:

- стабильная работа,
- открытый исходный код,
- активное комьюнити,
- легкость в разработке и доработке
- поддержка SEO.

В настоящее время рассматриваю вариант использования Next.js в режиме SSR, а также расматриваю вариант  GraphCommerce и @magento/pwa. Какие фреймворки вы бы порекомендовали для разработки фронтенд-части для Magento в 2023 году? Имеет ли смысл разрабатывать собственное решение в данной ситуации?